# replacing NA values with specific averege

Tags: r, mean, imputation

i have a data.frame with columns and rows. how could i replace NA values so that it would be the average of the first value before and after that cell in that column?

for example:

```
 1. 1 2  3 
 2. 4 NA 7
 3. 9 NA 8 
 4. 1 5  6
```

I need the first `NA` to be - `(5+2)/2=3.5`
and the second to `be (3.5+5)/2=4.25`

Comment: It's not really clear what your input data looks like. Are the numbers column vectors, row vectors? Do you have a `data.frame`? A `list`? A `matrix`? Under point 1, 2 and 4 you give three elements, while there are 4 elements under point 3. Please use `dput` to provide data in a reproducible and unambiguous format.

Comment: What's the replacement logic? Can it be generalised for(to?) all rows?

Comment: i edited it, is it better now?

Comment: @orifartook No not really. You didn't answer any of my questions. Do you have a `data.frame`? Or something else? You should edit your post to include the `dput` of your input sample data! If unclear review how to provide a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: it's a data.frame, and i am not familiar with the dput function

Comment: @orifartook Read the details of the post about reproducible examples that I link to! As it stands the quality of your post is very poor. Please spend some time familiarising yourself with general posting guidelines here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Lets create some sample data and transform it to `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
require(zoo)
dat <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, NA, 4)) 
setDT(dat)
```

Now, using the `zoo::na.approx` function we can impute the missing values.

```
dat[, newA:= na.approx(a, rule = 2)]
```

Output:

```
   a newA
1:  1    1
2:  2    2
3: NA    3
4:  4    4
```